# How to print all search matches in list of objects

Tags: python

This search function works but if I for example search for an animal called Sarah and there are two animals in the list called Sarah it only prints one of them. How should I do to make it print all the search matches?

```
def search():
choice = int(input("""
1 Name
2 Age
3 Specie
4 Gender
What do yo want to search for? """))

if choice == 1:
    your_search = input("Write the animal name: ").capitalize()
    for Animals in animal_list:
        if your_search == Animals.name:
            print(Animals)
            break

    else:
            print("Sorry, couldn't find any animal called " + your_search + ", maybe check the spelling.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing break after each successful match

Comment: I have tried to remove break but then it also prints the else statement even though it finds the searched animal in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the program to stop searching after it finds a result. Just remove the break command and add a marker stating if a name was found:

```
def search():
    choice = int(input("""
    1 Name
    2 Age
    3 Specie
    4 Gender
    What do yo want to search for? """))

    if choice == 1:
        your_search = input("Write the animal name: ").capitalize()
        found = False
        for Animals in animal_list:
            if your_search == Animals.name:
                found = True
                print(Animals)
        if found == False:
            print("Sorry, couldn't find any animal called " +
                  your_search + ", maybe check the spelling.")
```

Comment: I have tried that and then it prints the search matches but for some reason also the else statement.

Comment: Your else statement is not in the same line as the if statement, so after the if it's still going to read the else. You need to add four spaces in front of else to make it line up with the if statement.

Comment: But then it prints the else statement for every animal that doesn't match

Comment: I added a "found" variable that will remain false if nothing it found. Then at the end you check if it is still false and, if so, print your statement.